# c# discord.net How to get input while executing command

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I was making a discord bot using discord.net. Then, using the "search" command, I am going to receive a new chat and select a number from 1 to 5 to work. What should I do? This is part of the source code.

'''

```
[Command("search")]
public async Task Search()
{
    await ReplyAsync("Choose number from 1 to 5");

    int number = 0;

    //number = WaitCommand(); <= How can I make this?

    await ReplyAsync($"Your number is {number}.");
}
```

'''

No method parameters are available for this issue. Is there a way?

Comment: I highly doubt there is, as that would run into fundamental issues, such as: What do you do if the user does not provide any more input? How long do you wait for more input? You can't design asynchronously executed code this way

Comment: @UnholySheep If the user doesn't provide input for one minute, it will exit the function. Some discord bots like Ayana (js) provide similar functionality. Is this possible in c#?

Comment: I don't know how that bot works internally, but they way I'd assume it does it (and I have done something similar in another bot) is that it stores that information manually, e.g.: it has a lookup table somewhere, when a user started a specific operation and then has a timer running that will clear this out. Doing this in a generic library would be hard, as it doesn't know when you want to start a specific "state store", what to store or which operations reset such a timer

Comment: https://github.com/foxbot/Discord.Addons.Interactive

Comment: @Anu6is Thanks for your answer. How did you know that library? I've been searching for that feature on google for many hours, but I couldn't get the method after all.

Comment: It's the standard response for such questions in the library support channel - https://discord.gg/discord-api

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't already answered, you can add `params string[] args` as a parameter to your command's function. Everything a user writes after your command will then be parsed into that. I've modified your command to work with this.

```
[Command("search")]
    public async Task Search(params string[] args)
    {
        if(args.Length == 0 || !int.TryParse(args[0], out int number))
        {
            await ReplyAsync("You have to enter a number!");
            return;
        }

        await ReplyAsync($"Your number is {number}.");
    }
```

`[prefix]search` will now yield "You have to enter a number!"
`[prefix]search 3` outputs "Your number is 3."

Or if you rather want to ask the user for a number after they use the command you can save the current user's id and wait for his next message using `Discord.MessageReceived` and use that in another function.